# Apache URL rewrite throwing 500 error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I've recently been attempting to set up an Apache server on my local machine and everything is functional except certain URLs will throw a 500 error with no useful troubleshooting information.

I currently use a FallbackResource in my .htaccess file that will redirect any requests to a switchboard.php that handles routing. This works for localhost and urls that only have one slash, such as "localhost/Users" but anytime there is multiple directives, it crashes. Such as "localhost/Users/view."

The code uses the following regex and matching function to check for valid input, and it works in production, but I can't check the actual server settings to duplicate it.

```
preg_match('/(.*)\?/',$uri,$m)
```

Any ideas on what may be causing this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can I take a guess :)? Redirect loop.

Comment: It does in fact seem to be a looping issue. But it's strange that it works in production as is.

The log states "Request exceeded the limit of 10 subrequest nesting levels due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary."

So I'll look into that a bit more to see if I can't solve it.
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you need to *anchor* that regex to, say, the start `^` and/or the end `$` of the string...? Also notice that your regex is *greedily* looking for the *longest* chunk of anything-at-all which ends with a question mark.